# How to change public property value in design time using vs.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I am spending a number of days to solve this problem.
I have a custom control inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Test
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:MyCustomTextBox runat=server />")]
    public class MyCustomTextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
    {
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
        [DefaultValue(InputType.Enum1)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public InputType UserInputType { get; set; }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
        [DefaultValue(LetterCase.Enum3)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public LetterCase UserLetterCase { get; set; }
    }

    public enum InputType { Enum1, Enum2 }

    public enum LetterCase { Enum3, Enum4 }
}
```

I have found out some of System.ComponentModel attributes.

What I want to do is that if a user changes enum property of UserInputType to InputType.Enum2, then UserLetterCase property should be changed to LetterCase.Enum4.
And these all should happen in design time when using visual studio.net 2010.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing them as automatic properties, create backing fields and make the required changes in the `set` part:

```
    private InputType _userInputType;
    public InputType UserInputType
    {
        get
        {
            return _userInputType;
        }
        set
        {
            _userInputType = value;
            if (value == InputType.Enum2)
                UserLetterCase = LetterCase.Enum4;
        }
    }
```